# inserting data into Couchbase lite using cblite, one document per line in JSON file - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, couchbase-lite

I'm working on Couchbase lite, and I want to prepare a pre built database from a json file.
Each time I import the file which has an array of 12 keys, that has 100 line, each line is a single array.

Cblite imports all the file into a single document, which won't allow me to use the content of the document based on the keys, because all the 12 keys are duplicated 100 times. But I found out that i can import the single file into several documents (each line/array) and become a separate document.

But i’m not able to do that with the commands provided in cblite, I got error from cblite including (Can't parse json)

```
DESTINATION : Database path, replication URL, or JSON file path:
    *.cblite2 :  Copies local database file, and assigns new UUID to target
    *.cblite2 :  With --replicate flag, runs local replication [EE]
    ws://*    :  Networked replication
    wss://*   :  Networked replication, with TLS
    *.json    :  Imports/exports JSON file (one doc per line)
    */        :  Imports/exports directory of JSON files (one per doc)
```

I can rearrange the file of json anyway that fits… but I can’t create a single file for each array.

The arrays look like that

```
{"_id":13,"id":"51333591918","owner":"126542062@N08","secret":"16f1758279","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"dreamland","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"url_s":"https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51333591918_16f1758279_m.jpg","height_s":148,"width_s":240}
{"_id":14,"id":"51333156717","owner":"97978797@N03","secret":"82f0fb71aa","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"Tagpfauenauge","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"url_s":"https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51333156717_82f0fb71aa_m.jpg","height_s":160,"width_s":240}
```

```
cblite -tool version: cblite tool 2.8 EE
Couchbase lite version : 2.8.6
Error: NullPointerException
```

I tried several files. one JSON which is public file ( i used it as a test also) is the flickr json response [Flickr Photos Json File](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&api_key=a4c97bc78d162318a884fddb4c9fac78&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_s&page=2)

also I used the files of the company which are items for POS.

i tried to change the structure of the json files manually even. but all leading to the same result... (putting all the arrays in a single document)

in the db query i used this code

```
 val query = QueryBuilder
            .select(
                SelectResult.expression(Meta.id),
                SelectResult.property("owner"),
                SelectResult.property("secret"),
                SelectResult.property("server"),
                SelectResult.property("farm"),
                SelectResult.property("title"),
                SelectResult.property("ispublic"),
                SelectResult.property("isfriend"),
                SelectResult.property("isfamily"),
                SelectResult.property("url_s"),
                SelectResult.property("height_s"),
                SelectResult.property("width_s"),
            )
            .from(DataSource.database(database))

        val result = query.execute().allResults()

        for (rs in result) {
           // val doc = database.getDocument(photo.id)
            val id = rs.getString("id")
            val owner = rs.getString("owner")
            val secret = rs.getString("secret")
            val server = rs.getString("server")
            val farm = rs.getInt("farm")
            val title = rs.getString("title")
            val ispublic = rs.getInt("ispublic")
            val isfriend = rs.getInt("isfriend")
            val isfamily = rs.getInt("isfamily")
            val url_s = rs.getString("url_s")
            val height_s = rs.getInt("height_s")
            val width_s = rs.getInt("width_s")

            photoList.add(
                photo(
                    id!!,
                    owner!!,
                    secret!!,
                    server!!,
                    farm,
                    title!!,
                    ispublic,
                    isfriend,
                    isfamily,
                    url_s!!,
                    height_s,
                    width_s
                )
            )
```

i noticed in Kotlin the option of `SelectResult.all()`  doesn't bring anything, i have to specify the keys one by one to be fetched. but that is not an issue.

i often managed to print the whole document in the console, but i will never be able to use any key within. always getting the NullPointer as an error.

I'm still learning on couchbase and i looking to learn about N1QL, i rarely find something for Kotlin unfortunately

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the example repo in GitHub:
https://github.com/biozal/cbmobile-split-data-example

I made the assumption that all records in the photo array that is a child object of the photos object is what you wanted to save to the database and that each object you wanted to be a new document.

Given this I wrote a very simple shell script (using "bash") that does the following:

- get the count of how many items are in the document
- loop through the number of items I need to create documents for
- used the open source jq command (https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to get the content and save it into a variable named json
- each document needs a unique key so I used the id field for this and pull it from the json
- finally I call the cblite tool and have it create the document based on the id I pulled for the item and the json value of it

A screenshot of this query is provided named query-database.png.  To query I did the following:

```sh
./cblite sampleDb.cblite2
 query --limit 10 ["=", [".owner"], "138459774@N07"]
```

That query will return the document that the value is in.

Comment: thank you so much for your response... i opened terminal (i have ubuntu) and started the file --> ./parsedata.sh but i got these errors-->
./parsedata.sh: line 7: jq: command not found
./parsedata.sh: line 10: ((: count<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
./parsedata.sh: line 22: ./cblite: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
i gave the file the needed permission --> chmod 755 ./parsedata.sh
did i made anything wrong?

Comment: @KotlinStudent - jq has to be installed.  Since you are on Linux you should be able to use 

```bash
sudo apt-get install jq
```.  cblite  included in the project is the Mac OS X version - for the Linux version you would have to download it and replace the Mac version.  I have updated the repo directions to state this under troubleshooting.  If you feel my repo works, it would greatly help to mark it as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I installed jq, thank you for that... also got the ubuntu cblite file ... i opened termenal and started ./parsedata.sh but i got this --> error: ./cblite: error while loading shared libraries: libicuuc.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
is there is something i can do about it?... thank you so much for being committed to solve this issue... i believe many people will get use of it...

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Also in your original post you were already using the cblite tool.  Did you download a new version or copy the tool version you were already using?  I don't personally use Linux on a daily basis and my only Linux machine I have doesn't use Ubuntu so I'd need to know what version you are using to test.

Comment: okey... THANK YOU SO MUCH... I will post this to couchbase forum, they will definitely get use of it... I tried it on another json file, had to open the file in text edit, (never did this before) but found out that it can be easily edited to fit the file structure... it is working automatically and perfectly... keep up the good work

Comment: One note about the last issue. i had to move the files you created inside the /bin file of the cblite-tool to make it function correctly...